# Tkinter window not closing despite quit() and destroy()

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm running Tkinter to get a file path using the function filedialog.askopenfilename(). The program is getting the file path correctly but once I click "Open" on the file I want, the code destroy() does not destroy the GUI window that is open.

I've tried both the destroy() and the quit() functions, though I read that destroy() is preferred. I read that if I do root.destroy(), it is supposed to destroy the GUI that is open. What is happening is that, after the user picks a file, then clicks open, the finder window then becomes totally greyed out and unresponsive. I'm guessing this is the point at which we can execute a destroy, but it's not working for me.

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong. Would really like to delete the Tkinter browser. My code does continue executing despite the browser being open, but it's unprofessional.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() #use to hide tkinter window

def search_for_file_path ():
    currdir = os.getcwd()
    tempdir = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir=currdir, title='Please select a directory')
    if len(tempdir) > 0:
        print ("You chose: %s" % tempdir)
    return tempdir


file_path_variable = search_for_file_path()
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.destroy()
print ("\nfile_path_variable = ", file_path_variable)
```

Comment: Why do you create two instances of TK?

Comment: You're right,  there is no need, I was checking to see if that was the problem, but adding the second one didn't fix it. Having just one doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you see the two messages (from `print(...)`) in the console?

Comment: When I remove the unnecessary second instance of `Tk`, your code works exactly as I would expect.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I do see the two print statements. So the code is running to the bottom correctly without problem. It's just not managing to close the window that's open, was my interpretation.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hm, that's interesting. It's still not working when I run it.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have fixed the problem! When I execute the script from the terminal, instead of clicking "run" inside the python app, it works. I'm not sure why one works and not the other, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

remove the second instance

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() #use to hide tkinter window

def search_for_file_path ():
    currdir = os.getcwd()
    tempdir = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir=currdir, title='Please select a directory')
    if len(tempdir) > 0:
        print ("You chose: %s" % tempdir)
    return tempdir


file_path_variable = search_for_file_path()
# remove the second instance
root.destroy()
print ("\nfile_path_variable = ", file_path_variable)
```

Comment: Hi Ayoub, removing the second instance does not work either. :/ It is still giving me the greyed out finder window. If it is working for you, maybe it is specific to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me than I would use `root.mainloop()` and then `root.destroy()`. There are other ways but I am not sure if they work.